# Revit Addin OnStartUp

Tags: autodesk, revit-api, revit, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to implement a Revit ADDIN which completes a process upon launch. Currently I am trying to load a revit file as soon as Revit is launched, I just want to understand how to create an addin which is completed upon launch..

The program launches fine without having any connection issues between the files, but nothing happens... no file is loaded automatically but no errors?

I'm unsure as to where I'm going wrong as to my knowledge this shown automatically launch my Revit file?
*Ignore the nonrelated name assigned to the program

Class1.cs

```
using System;
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using System.Reflection;


namespace AreaChecker
{
        class Class1 : IExternalApplication
    {

        const string _test_project_filepath
                = "c:/Users/Test/Desktop/Forge/models/123.rvt";

        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication a)
        {
            a.ControlledApplication.ApplicationInitialized
              += OnApplicationInitialized;

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        void OnApplicationInitialized(
          object sender,
          ApplicationInitializedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Sender is an Application instance:

            Application app = sender as Application;

            // However, UIApplication can be 
            // instantiated from Application.

            UIApplication uiapp = new UIApplication(app);

            uiapp.OpenAndActivateDocument(
              _test_project_filepath);
        }

        public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication a)
        {
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

AreaChecker.ADDIN

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<RevitAddIns>
        <AddIn Type="Application">
        <Name>AreaChecker</Name>
                <Assembly>C:\Users\Test\source\repos\AreaChecker\AreaChecker\bin\Debug\AreaChecker.dll</Assembly>
                <AddInId>d48038f8-ba7c-4894-818d-3f8bef5f802d</AddInId>
                <FullClassName>AreaChecker.Class1</FullClassName>
                <Text>AreaChecker.Class1</Text> 
                <VendorId>NAME</VendorId>
                <VendorDescription>Your Company Information</VendorDescription> 
        </AddIn>
</RevitAddIns>
```

*Note: I am fairly familiar with Revit Command Addin's, just not applications so I understand the connected between the class and the addin files through the dll*

Comment: Not sure, but can you perhaps make your class public? 
eg: public class Class1: IExternalApplication {...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see any obvious problem with the code you have posted.

However, instead of trying to find the error, I prefer to point you to a correct and tested solution that I published just yesterday, demonstrating how to [auto-run an add-in for Forge Design Automation](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/09/auto-run-an-add-in-for-design-automation.html).

It makes use of an external DB application instead of an external (UI) application like you have, but the principles remain unchanged.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, is there anything along the lines of an ADDIN which launches a dialog box (for example) onstartup?

Comment: Also, I am using visual studio, could it be a possibility the solution type is wrong? It's currently C# Web>.NET Framework 4.7